# Programa de tirar dados y elegir dos numeros aleatorios y sumarlos

Tags: python-3.x

Les quería solicitar la ayuda, soy nuevo en la programación y necesito que me guíen en como hacer un programa que simule la tirada de dados.

Cada vez que ejecutamos el programa, éste elegirá dos números aleatorios entre el 1 y el 6. El programa deberá imprimirlos en pantalla, imprimir su suma y preguntarle al usuario si quiere tirar los dados otra vez.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidos a stackoverflow. Por favor postear lo que ha probado en codigo, y describe en cual parte tienes problema. Lee el guia [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hola @Jose Garcia . Como eres nuevo puede que no lo sepas, pero es necesario que pongas tú código, lo que has intentado y las trazas de error para poder ayudarte. StackOverflow es una comunidad de dudas sobre programación, no donde se le dan hechos ejercicios de clase a los alumnos.

Answer (score 1):

Hola muy buenas primero creamos una función para  facilitar el uso

```py
# importar librería random para números al azar
import random

def lanzar():
    # la función randint selecciona un numero al azar que este entre a y b
    # su formato es randint(a, b)
    PrimerNumero = random.randint(1,6) 
    SegundoNumero = random.randint(1,6)
    # una vez elegido los dos numeros los vamos a mostrar
    print(f"El primer dado es: {PrimerNumero}")
    print(f"El primer dado es: {SegundoNumero}")
    # la letra f antes del print es una de las formas de formatear los string
    printf(f"El resultado es {PrimerNumero + SegundoNumero}")
    

while (True): # ciclo infinito para preguntar
    Respuesta = input("¿Quiere lanzar otra vez? (si/no): ")
    if Respuesta.lower() == "si": # lo pasamos a minúsculas para eso el .lower()
        lanzar() 
    else:
        break #es para terminar el ciclo infinito
```

Para mas información sobre la librería random [click aquí](https://j2logo.com/python/generar-numeros-aleatorios-en-python/)

Para mas información sobre los formateo de string [click aquí](https://pybonacci.org/2020/02/05/formateando-texto-en-python/)

Para mas información sobre la función lower [click aquí](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/lower)

Para mas información sobre break [click aquí](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-break-continue-and-pass-statements-when-working-with-loops-in-python-3-es)

Answer (score -1):

## Este programa simula un juego de dados

import random

res = input("Desea lanzar los dados de nuevo: S/N");
while(res == 'S'):

```
n1 = random.randint(1,6);
n2 = random.randint(1,6);

print(("El dado uno cayo en: ") + str(n1) + " y el dado dos en:" + str(n2));
print("La suma de los dos dados es:" + str(n1 + n2) + "\n");


res = input("Desea lanzar los dados de nuevo: S/N");
```

Comment: Al margen de eso, por favor lee [answer], considera editar y mejorar esta publicación explicando el código, pues la pregunta tiene problemas de formato y quedará cerrada y la respuesta (al momento) no explica como esto soluciona el problema